# Loading Texture2D crashes in fullscreen, hangs in windows mode

Tags: macos, mono, xna, monogame, xamarin-studio

I downloaded and installed the latest version of Xamarin Studio and MonoGame. I then created a brand new `MonoMac` project.

[image]

I added a .jpg file to my /Content directory and tried to load it using `Content.Load<Texture2D>`

[image]

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Game1 ()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager (this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";              
        graphics.IsFullScreen = false;      
    }

    protected override void Initialize ()
    {
        base.Initialize ();

    }

    protected override void LoadContent ()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch (GraphicsDevice);
        Content.Load<Texture2D> ("woodroom");
    }

    protected override void Update (GameTime gameTime)
    {
        #if !__IOS__
        if (GamePad.GetState (PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed ||
            Keyboard.GetState ().IsKeyDown (Keys.Escape)) {
            Exit ();
        }
        #endif

        base.Update (gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw (GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear (Color.CornflowerBlue);
        base.Draw (gameTime);
    }
}
```

When I call `Content.Load<Texture2D>` the app hangs. I have set the `woodroom.jpg` so that it Copies to Output when newer and I've changed it's Build Action to `Content`

[image]

When the app runs, this is all I get in Windowed is the hung app, not even the rendered CornFlowerBlue:

[image]

When I run in fullscreen it generates a [detailed message](https://gist.github.com/scionwest/f2f900c7a070f5268e6d) that is to long for me to include in this post.

What is happening that causes the app to hang forever, or crash, when I attempt to load the content?

Comment: You must symbolicate the crash log to see in which function of your code it's crashing.

Comment: How does one go about doing that?

Comment: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61992/how-to-symbolicate-stack